# Проблема с функцией print в Phyton

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = input()
print("The next number for the number " a "is" a+1)
```

При выполнении вылетает ошибка

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "python", line 3
>       print("The next number for the number " a "is" a+1)
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Но проблем с синтаксисом в упор не вижу. Где косяк, и можно ли подкинуть подробной литературы по этому вопросу?

Comment: Вообще какая задача ?

Comment: Уже не актуально, но требовалось вывести a+1 и a-1 к введенному числу. Простые задачки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте запятые между параметрами, которые выводите:

```
print("The next number for the number ", a ,"is", a+1)
```

Более того. Сейчас `a` -- строка. Что значит прибавить к ней 1 не ясно. Преобразуйте её в число:

```
a = int(input())
```